# Installing Docker on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I'm trying to install Docker on CentOS 6.6 64 bit version. When execute

```
sudo yum install docker
```

I get this

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: mirrors.psychz.net
  * extras: centos-distro.cavecreek.net
  * updates: distro.ibiblio.org
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Your configured repositories do not contain a docker package. You need to enable one that does.

Answer (score 26):

Epel repository is not installed.
Run

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

and then run

```
sudo yum install docker-io
```

Comment: This answer do longer appears to work (`Package epel-release-6-8.noarch already installed and latest version`; `No package docker-io available`).

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer [here](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-6/)

I needed to add the EPEL repository where Docker can be found.

Answer (score 4):

Log into your machine as a user with sudo or root privileges.

Make sure your existing yum packages are up-to-date.

```
$ sudo yum update
```

Run the Docker installation script.

```
$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

This script adds the `docker.repo` repository and installs Docker.
Start the Docker daemon.

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

Comment: this is not working anymore for centos 6.6

# curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: f45d7c11389849ff46a6b4d94e0dd1ffebca32c1

ERROR: Unsupported distribution ''

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming here for the same issue with RedHat, use

```
sudo yum install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhui-REGION-rhel-server-extras
sudo yum install docker
```