# How to installing docker on centos 6

Tags: docker, centos, centos6

Been trying to install docker on centos 6 at work (They do not want to upgrade to Centos 7) but I am having dependency issues.

```
    Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.6-3.3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.1-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
```

Comment: `To install Docker Engine - Community, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7. Archived versions aren’t supported or tested.` <- https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#prerequisites. If your workplace is against upgrading software, then run, Forrest, run! But that's only my opinion and it's not on topic, I'm sorry.

Comment: CentOS 6 is almost EOL, you could use this as an argument to push for updating to minimal required version. If this is not an option, then... I have to agree with @AlexKarshin.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you both @AlexKarshin  Danila Kiver

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. EPEL used to have a package called docker-io, but it appears that is no longer the case. I've never heard of EPEL dropping a package like that. So I'm stuck too. BTW. Almost EOL doesn't mean EOL, and it also shouldn't mean that an old version that used to work should be gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Docker on CentOS 6 after removal of docker-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134196/installing-docker-on-centos-6-after-removal-of-docker-io)