# Docker not running

Tags: docker, daemon, cloudera-cdh

I am using Cloudera Vm and trying to work with docker. I have installed it, but maybe there is something wrong with the installation. I tried to uninstall it and install it again clearly, but still the same issue.

I followed the steps for installation here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#install-using-the-repository

And after the following command

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

I got the following errors at the end. Could that be the reason of my issues and if yes how can I fix these? (I tried the suggestions at the end of the error message but they did not help)

```
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-nightly)
           Requires: libseccomp
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-nightly)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-nightly)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
Error: Package: 3:docker-ce-19.03.13-1.2.beta2.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-test)
           Requires: libseccomp >= 2.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Below you can see some of the commands which I tried.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo docker --version Docker version
19.03.13-beta2, build ff3fbc9d55

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ docker image ls
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
ls: cannot access /var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service docker start
docker: unrecognized service

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo service docker.io start
docker.io: unrecognized service

docker: 'ls' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13-beta2
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.14
 Git commit:        ff3fbc9d55
 Built:             Mon Aug  3 15:04:07 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
ls: cannot access /var/run/docker.sock: No such file or directory
```

Can you maybe see the problem or give me a hint what command should I run for more information?

Comment: Do you follow the installation steps in the docker documentation?

Comment: @DanielMarques yes, sure

Comment: Definitely something went wrong in your docker installation. Please paste here the link from where you did follow the steps... Also during the installation do you notice something strange?

Comment: Another thing is that I suggest you installing a stable version like `19.03.12`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this, thank you. I updated my question.

Comment: What version of centos are you using in the Cloudera VM?

Comment: I almost sure you enable the nightly or test repositories during the installation, this is generally a bad idea because these versions are with some bugs that they are fixing before the stable version being released. I think the best thing to do is uninstall then install the last stable docker release. Examplo: `sudo yum install docker-ce-19.03.12 docker-ce-cli-19.03.12 containerd.io`

Comment: Is this CentOS 7 (not CentOS 8)? https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#os-requirements

Comment: @Howard_Roark I have CentOS release 6.10 (final). And I checked the websites with the tutorials how to install it on centos 6 and it isn't working.. it is giving me these errors again.

Comment: @DanielMarques this command is also not working. I disabled the nightly and test repositories as well...

Comment: I think Docker isn't supported on Centos6 based on what I read before I asked you that question

Comment: It could be that. @Howard_Roark CentOS 6 will reach the end of life in November 2020. It's possible creating CentOS 6 VMs on Cloudera, but not install docker on it. I cannot think of another reason that explains the current behavior of docker within your VM. Isn't possible for you creating a CentOS 7 VM and install docker in it?

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, I don't think Docker is supported on CentOS6.  You can see that a previous poster [ran into this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483379/installing-docker-on-centos-6-6) as well.  And you can see in the [Prerequisites](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/#os-requirements) in the instructions that you are following that they say you need CentOS7.

> To install Docker Engine, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7. Archived versions aren’t supported or tested.

Redhat provides a short explanation [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1378023) of why Docker doesn't work well with RHEL6.

> Many of the docker project's features are tied to capabilities in the RHEL 7 kernel as well as various infrastructure component updates like devicemapper for thin provisioning, direct LVM, sVirt and systemd